# Having Excel function VBA connection to SQL issue - Compile Error

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Hi I am trying to run a function in my excel table where a query is run through the function and data is generated but I have managed to fix the query which works when I use in SQL but when I run the function from Excel I get the following error:

> Compile Error:  User-defined type not defined.

**error which I get in EXCEL VB:**

[image]

The function I am running is:

```vb
Function Download_Standard_BOM(Query As String)
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim StrQuery As String

    ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=STORESYSTEM 
;Database=STORE;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    StrQuery = Query 'Sheets("Tests Scenario").Range("J2").Offset(i, 0).Value
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 100
    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    Download_Standard_BOM = rst("NAME")
End Function
```

and the SQL query I am running is:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 NAME
FROM [SERVER].[dbo].[STORE]
WHERE SecurityE = 'SGX' AND
      Trans = ' 0' AND
      Type = '9' AND
      Status = '0' AND
      SubId = 'Reversal'
```

Comment: have you checked to see that all your VBA reference are ok? (i.e. none of them have 'Missing' infront of them). Also, which line throws the error?

Comment: Yes none of them have missing in VBA references

Comment: First wrap function in [error handling](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) to possibly get a more specific error message. And where is the SQL query derived? Show VBA assignment of *Query* string. Try `debug.Print StrQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the reference to

> Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library

[image]